# Removing edges to eliminate all but one cycle-free path between two nodes

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I have a connected undirected graph having *n* nodes. Given two nodes, I want to find the minimum number of edges that would have to be removed in order to ensure that there's only one cycle-free path between those two nodes.

For  example, if this is the graph:

```
1------------2------------5
|                         | 
|                         | 
3-------------------------4
```

then given the nodes `1` and `5`, the answer will be **1**: just remove (for example) the edge between node 3 and node 4.

The brute-force approach is, for each subset of the set of edges, to try removing those edges and test if there's a unique cycle-free path between the two nodes of interest.

Is there a more efficient approach? (I Googled it, but did not find anything relevant.)

---

*(Dear cryptomanic, I added these examples to help in the discussion about the exact requirements; please edit this part and indicate which of these solutions are valid. m69)*

Input graph: (going from X to Y)

```
          O---O---O---O       O
         /     \ /     \     / \
O---O---X       O       Y---O---O
         \             /
          O---O---O---O
             / \       \
            O---O       O
```

Solution A: (no cycles inbetween X and Y)

```
          O---O---O---O       O
         /       /     \     / \
O---O---X       O       Y---O---O
                       /
          O---O---O---O
             / \       \
            O---O       O
```

Solution B: (no side-paths inbetween X and Y)

```
          O---O---O---O       O
         /             \     / \
O---O---X       O       Y---O---O
                       /
          O---O---O---O
             / \       \
            O---O       O
```

Solution C: (no cycles connected to X and Y)

```
          O---O---O---O       O
         /       /     \       \
O---O---X       O       Y---O---O
                       /
          O---O---O   O
             / \       \
            O---O       O
```

Solution D: (completely isolate path from X to Y)

```
          O---O---O---O       O
         /             \     / \
O---O   X       O       Y   O---O

          O---O---O---O
             / \       \
            O---O       O
```

Solution E: (P can only be used once, so P-Q-R-P is not part of an alternative path)

```
          O---O---O---O       O
               \ /           / \
O---O---X       O       Y   O---O
         \             /
          O---P---O---O
             / \       \
            Q---R       O
```

Solution F:

```
          O---O---O---O       O
               \ /     \     / \
O---O---X       O       Y---O---O
         \             /
          O---O---O---O
             / \       \
            O---O       O
```

Comment: So if there is an edge between 1 and n, should all other edges connected to 1 or n be removed?

Comment: @m69 it depends. You have to remove minimum edges so that there exists one path from node 1 to node n.

Comment: Use any method to find a cycle that has 1 and n in it; when you do, remove one of the cycle's edges. (1 and n are still connected, because you can just "go round the other way".) Repeat this until there are no more cycles containing 1 and n.

Comment: @m69: There are two problems with that approach. Problem #1: The two paths might be `1-2-3-5-6` and `1-2-4-5-6`. Then there's no cycle containing `1` and `6`. So your approach can abort "early". Problem #2: A clever choice of the edge to remove might simultaneously eliminate many paths. Your approach may not always give the optimal choice, so might end up removing unnecessarily many edges.

Comment: You could find all paths from 1 to n, then start walking them from both ends, until they split up in different directions, and then remove the edges that are part of the most paths, then walk further until they split again... But that's not going to be very efficient.

Comment: @AnthonyLabarre consider the graph having 6 nodes and 7 edges(1-2, 2-3, 3-4, 2-4, 4-5, 5-6, 1-6). Given nodes are 1 and 6. The answer will be 1 when we remove the edge(1-2 or 4-5 or 5-6) from the longest path.

Comment: Every edge in a minimum cut between the two given vertices u and v is part of a distinct path between them, so |MinCut(u, v)|-1 is a lower bound on the number of edges you'll need to delete.  You could recurse (or better: use branch and bound) to try leaving in each of the |MinCut(u, v)| edges (a, b) and deleting the others, giving you 2 subproblems to solve each time (snip (a, b) as well to produce 2 separate components, and then solve both RemoveMinEdges(u, a) and RemoveMinEdges(b, v)), but this will still be exponential-time.  It might be possible to reduce from Feedback Arc Set.

Comment: @maraca Not necessarily; they could be "behind" n, i.e. you'd have to go through n to reach the cycle from 1. Then the cycle would be irrelevant. At least that's how I interpret the question, but it isn't completely clear.

Comment: @m69 all of your solutions(A to E) satisfies the condition that there exists one simple path from node X to Y. But none of them are optimal. Solution F is optimal(only one edge is removed).

Comment: @j_random_hacker nice approach but how we can say that the approach will give the optimal result(edges removed will be minimum).